# Mongoose .populate() only showing 1 document

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to output just the hometeam name's to the page so that I can try to understand how to work with my code better. It is only printing one team to the page, and it is printing all the details of that team to the page, whereas I only want it to print one part.

This is my code, I want it to print the name's of each `hometeam` to the page

```
  app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
    Match.findOne({}).populate('hometeam.name').exec(function(err, teams){
      util.log(teams);
      res.send(teams);
    });
  });
```

But when I load the page all I get is the first piece of data from this list of Matches

```
[
  {
    "hometeam": "5106e7ef9afe3a430e000007",
    "_id": "5113b7ca71ec596125000005",
    "__v": 0,
    "key": 1360246730427
  },
  {
    "hometeam": "5113c13e0eea687b28000001",
    "_id": "5113e951354fe70330000001",
    "__v": 0,
    "key": 1360259409361
  },
  {
    "hometeam": "5113c13e0eea687b28000001",
    "_id": "5113e999354fe70330000002",
    "__v": 0,
    "key": 1360259481412
  }
]
```

Also, if I try to put `util.log(teams.hometeam.name)` I get the following:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined
```

But I would want it to be able to print the name which belongs to hometeam here. As hometeam is just the objectId of a Team in my database, am I missing something with the DBreferencing here?

Update:

Team Schema

```
var Team = new Schema({
  'key' : {
    unique : true,
    type : Number,
    default: getId
  },
  'name' : { type : String,
              validate : [validatePresenceOf, 'Team name is required'],
              index : { unique : true }
            }
});

module.exports.Schema = Team;
module.exports.Model = mongoose.model('Team', Team);
```

Match Schema

```
var Team = require('../schemas/Team').Schema;

var Match = new Schema({
  'key' : {
    unique: true,
    type: Number,
    default: getId
  },
  'hometeam' : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Team' },
  'awayteam' : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Team' }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Match', Match);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Populate takes the property name of the property you are trying to retrieve. This means that you should use 'hometeam' instead of 'hometeam.name'. However, you want to retrieve the name of the team so you could filter for that. The call would then become..

```
Match.findOne({}).populate('hometeam', {name: 1}).exec(function(err, teams)
```

Now you have a property called 'hometeam' with in that the name. Have fun :)

**EDIT**

Showing how to have a single mongoose instance in more files to have correct registration of schemas.

**app.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Team = require('./schemas/team-schema')(mongoose);
var Match = require('./schemas/match-schema')(mongoose);
// You can only require them like this ONCE, afterwards FETCH them.
var Team = mongoose.model('Team'); // LIKE THIS
```

**schemas/match-schema.js**

```
module.exports = function(mongoose) {
    var Match = new mongoose.Schema({
        'key' : {
            unique: true,
            type: Number,
            default: getId
        },
        'hometeam' : { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Team' },
        'awayteam' : { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Team' }
    });
    return mongoose.model('Match', Match);
};
```

**schemas/team-schema.js**

```
module.exports = function(mongoose) {
    var Team = new mongoose.Schema({
        'key' : {
            unique : true,
            type : Number,
            default: getId
        },
        'name' : { type : String,
            validate : [validatePresenceOf, 'Team name is required'],
            index : { unique : true }
        }
    });
    return mongoose.model('Team', Team);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This gave me `"hometeam": null,` in the response and still only gave me one piece of data. Please look at the update to the end of the original post, I'm unsure why but if I try to print the name of the `hometeam` I get that error, `hometeam` is storing the `ObjectId` of the `Team` stored there. So how would I go about retrieving that `Team's` name?

Comment: @germainelol Would you mind updating your question with the scheme for Team and Match? There might be either a wrong reference (the ref variable) or the ObjectId being pointed at does not exist. I suspect the former, but either is a likely problem.

Comment: The schemes are fine, @germainelol. I can think of two more options to try. First, make sure that the ObjectId of the hometeam is really valid (_id of a document in the team collection). Use a tool such as MongoVUE to confirm. Second, make sure you register each scheme/model in the same mongoose instance. If you do require('mongoose') again, both mongoose instances are not aware of each other. The latter might be more likely to be the issue you ran into.

Comment: I have checked the id's to check that it is indeed an id of a Team. Could you explain what you meant in the second suggestion more? Do you mean I should require the Team Schema/Model in the Match file, and the Match Schema/Model in the Team file? Don't think I follow.

Comment: You have a file for each schema. If you include mongoose in each file, you get two instances of mongoose. Each instance of mongoose has ONE schema (the one defined in THAT file), but does NOT know of the other schema. You should have ONE mongoose instance. I'll update my answer to give a brief example.

Comment: Thanks, I get the idea, but I'm not sure how I should be implementing my code so that it rectifies this problem.

Comment: I have included this in my code for Team, Match and my index I am using, but I still get `null` when trying to get the `hometeam.name` data?

Comment: Use the first change I suggest in my answer too, it is 'hometeam', not 'hometeam.name'. I have tested with some sample data (after removing some stuff you didn't provide, such as getId function) and the complete answer and this worked without issues.

Comment: It is currently at `hometeam` but it still gives back `null` for `hometeam` for some reason. I just want it to print out the `name` for each `hometeam` rather than the id, key etc for each `hometeam`

Comment: Is it possible for you to check my code, I must be doing something wrong if yours works with some sample data.

Comment: If you can make your entire code base available I can take a look. But I don't know how much of it is secret or anything, so you'll have to decide on an abstraction yourself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24143/discussion-between-germainelol-and-roel-van-uden)